# Is there a trigonometric Fourier transform formula?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I wonder if one can express the Fourier transform in the trigonometric approach like, say, in the case of the Fourier series, where we can write it as:

$Sf(x)=\frac{a_{0}}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left [ a_{n}cos\frac{n\pi x}{L} + b_{n}sin\frac{n\pi x}{L} \right ]$, where $L=\frac{T}{2}$,

$a_{n}=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)cos\frac{n\pi x}{L}dx$,

$b_{n}=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}dx$.

Can we infer from the above formulas the formula for the Fourier transform? If so, how? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sure, use Eulers formula $e^{-itx}=\cos(tx) - i\sin(tx)$.

Comment: Could you please write the whole formula? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you asking? What did you try?

Comment: So, basically, I have $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-xt}dt$, where $x$ is the n'th element of the transform, say, from 0 to 100, and $t$ takes values, say, from the range 0 to 1000. Now, for the each $x$ element (i.e 0 to 100) I calculate the integral for the $t$ range $\left \langle 0;1000 \right \rangle$, right? Now, according to the Euler's Identity, I can write $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)(cos(tx)-isin(tx))dt$? But can I took an absolute value from the $cos(tx)-isin(tx)$ for the integral calculation, so I could get a real result of $F(x)$?

Comment: Note that you should not restrict the variables, also your formula misses an $i$...

Comment: What do you mean by "restrict the variables"? About the missing &i& - yeah I noticed. Sorry and thank you.

Comment: The Fourier transform F of a function f is a function from R to C, i.e. the Fourier transform of a real function is usually not a real function. However, you do need some condition on f in order to define F. I suggest you look it up in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

With

$$F(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt$$

you get

$$F(\omega)=\int_0^{\infty}f(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt+\int_0^{\infty}f(-t)e^{i\omega t}dt$$

With $e^{i\omega t}=cos(\omega t)+i\sin(\omega t)$

you obtain

\begin{align}
F(\omega)&=\int_0^{\infty}[f(t)+f(-t)]\cos(\omega t)dt-i\int_0^{\infty}[f(t)-f(-t)]\sin(\omega t)dt\\
& = 2\int_0^{\infty}f_e(t)\cos(\omega t)dt -2i\int_0^{\infty}f_o(t)\sin(\omega t)dt
\end{align}

where

$$f_e(t)=\frac{f(t)+f(-t)}{2}\\
f_o(t)=\frac{f(t)-f(-t)}{2}$$

are the even and odd parts of $f(t)$, respectively.